# Change User default validation in Loopback

Tags: validation, loopbackjs

I'm developping a Loopback application extending base `User` model to `UserCode` model where each user is identified by an `email` *plus* a `code` fields.

So that a user can register with the same email twice but with different code.

I've seen that in `node_modules/loopback/common/models/user.js` at line 691 there is:

```
UserModel.validatesUniquenessOf('email', {message: 'Email already exists'});
```

I want to delete this restriction/validation but without change loopback code, of course.

How can I do it?
Maybe in the boot script I can loop through all validation and delete this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out

In this case you need to remove the default validations set by the User model

> `common/models/userCode.js`

```
module.exports = function(UserCode){
   //Add this line and it will start receiving multiple email.
   delete UserCode.validations.email;
}
```

Also you can play with the `required:true|false` property to make any default defined property required or not.

> common/models/userCode.json

```
{
  "name": "UserCode",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: @nkint check the answer now. I have edited. Its working

Comment: ok yeah I have reached similar solution.. not just deleting all validation but just uniqueness.. using `slice` .. is threre a better way?

Comment: @nkint Right now. I think that's the only way. there has been a discussion going on regarding this issue.
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1137

Answer (score 1):

The following code [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33881608/3025856) will remove ALL the email validations:

```
module.exports = function(UserCode){
   //Add this line and it will start receiving multiple email.
   delete UserCode.validations.email;
}
```

Instead be selective and do something like this:

```
   module.exports = function(UserCode){
      // remove ONLY email uniqueness validation 
      UserCode.validations.email = UserCode.validations.email.reduce((all, one) => {
        if (one.validation !== 'uniqueness') {
          all.push(one);
        }
        return all;
      }, []);
    }
```